# flask Redirect to content detail after added brings internal server error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am creating a new content in flask which supposed to be redirected to its detail view. i.e create page and it's preview. but returns Internal server error. can you please help inspect the code?

```
@deliverables.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def deliverables_add():
    form = RegionForm(request.form)
    form.regions.choices = [('', '--- Select Region ---')] + [(region.id, region.region) for region in db.session.query(Region).all()]
    forms = ProjectForm()
    if forms.validate_on_submit():
        pmodel = Project(title=forms.title.data,
                         description=forms.description.data,
                         baseline=forms.baseline.data,
                         performance_indicator=forms.performance_indicator.data,
                         budget=forms.budget.data,
                         author=1,
                         posted_date=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                         start_date=forms.started.data,
                         est_completion=forms.estimated_completion.data,
                         sector=forms.sector.data.id,
                         region=form.regions.data,
                         district=form.districts.data,
                         subdistrict=form.subdistricts.data,
                         village=form.villages.data)
        db.session.add(pmodel)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('New entry was successfully posted')
        redirect(deliv_view(cid=pmodel.id))
    return render_template('ginn/deliverables_add.html', forms=forms, form=form)

@deliverables.route('/<int:cid>')
def deliv_view(cid):
    projects = [(project.title, project.description,
                 project.region, project.district,
                 project.subdistrict, project.baseline,
                 project.performance_indicator, project.budget,
                 project.author, project.posted_date,
                 project.start_date, project.est_completion, project.mark_complete, project.activities,
                 project.remarks, project.sector, project.media) for project in Project.query.filter(Project.id==cid)]
    return render_template('ginn/deliview.html', projects = projects)
```

what am I not doing right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the handler function inside the redirect call. That's not how it works; you need to redirect to a URL.

```
return redirect(url_for('deliv_view', cid=pmodel.id))
```

Comment: I have successfully applied as you said but the page is not redirecting. it brings back the same page. Flashed messages are also not displayed.

Comment: You need to actually return the redirect.

Comment: @David Roseman   please this is how I have made the the template block, 

from the main block i have:

`{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for category, message in messages %}
      <li class="{{ category }}">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}`
and from the child theme i have 
`{% extends "ginn/index.html" %}
{% block body %}
{{ projects }}
{% endblock %}` But Messages aren't flasked and the output is

Comment: [(u'Welcome to a new projects', u'<p>Welcome to the new project line</p>\r\n', 7, 21, 253, u'this is the baseline', u'this is hte performance,', 23.0, 1, datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 11, 11, 23, 57, 71638), datetime.datetime(2006, 3, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2006, 1, 5, 0, 0), False, <sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery object at 0x7fa5c5f408d0>, , 1, [])]

Comment: can you please give a hint of how to properly format the output and get the flashed message?

Comment: Please ask a new question with the code properly formatted.

Comment: Oops, I have to wait for 90 mins